# Path::Class::Unicode and error handling

Tags: perl, file-io, error-handling, perl-module

[Path::Class::Unicode](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass%3a%3aUnicode): Do I have to check on `ufile` and `open` for errors on my own or is it done automatically?

```
use Path::Class::Unicode;

my $file = ufile( "filename" );
my $fh = $file->open;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ufile` is just a wapper for the constructor of the class, which should not throw any errors.

The `open` method is a wapper around the constructor for `IO::File` (or `IO::Dir`, for that matter). The `new` method on `IO::File` can throw an error for invalid arguments, but otherwise returns either a file handle, or the normal return values of `open`, `sysopen` etc. However, this is wrapped by `IO::File` to return either a valid file handle, or `undef`.

Therefore, you should perform your own error handling:

```
my $fh = $file->open or die "Could not open $filename: $!";
# do not use the stringification of $file, as that would be a byte string
```

I am not sure if Path::Class::Unicode has significant benefits considering how different OSes handle unicode filenames. It is usually best to consider file names as *binary* data, which is how the current `open` builtin works.